# Compile and run java code from Terminal using ANT on OS X

Tags: java, macos, ant, terminal

I installed ANT on my mac and tried the tutorial here http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

so, that is all windows syntax, are there any OS X tutorials?

anyway I created a text file HelloWorld.java.... in the directory src/oata/HelloWorld.java

```
package oata;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

than I created the directory src/oata/build/classes

how can I compile an run the file now?

Comment: The syntax should be pretty much the same. Ant is a cross-platform project. What is your specific problem?

Comment: Well, then you are just not in the directory that contains the file "src/ota/HelloWorld.java". That has nothing to do with Ant (you don't even use Ant here!) and neither with OS X vs. Windows. Btw. shouldn't it be "oata" instead of just "ota" in your command?

Comment: Yes, that was an typing mistake ;) so, now is can compile it and the file HelloWorld.class was created. But when I try: java -cp src/build/classes oata.HelloWorld I get the message: Error: Could not find or load main class src.oata.HelloWorld

Comment: That's impossible. If you ask it to execute "oata.HelloWorld", it will never answer that it can't find "src.oata.HelloWorld". Java doesn't just invent the "src." prefix.

Comment: Hmmm, I did it again and now it works -.- Thank you so far, I will continue the tutorial and maybe I get an other question ;)